# Text-centering with larger numbers?

Tags: html, css

In a picture the problem is:

[i.stack.imgur.com/ryV96.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryV96.png)

In details:
I'm trying to keep the "voteTotal" centered as it increases to larger (say two or three digits) numbers.  I've fiddled with various "text-align" and css properties (as well as div-wrappers) but I can't figure out why larger numbers are not centered properly.  Any thoughts?

HTML:

```
<span>
  <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up voteButton upvoted"></button>
  <h4 class="voteTotal">10</h4>
  <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down voteButton"></button>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.voteButton {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.voteTotal {
  display: block;
  margin: -.5em auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: using a fixed-width or variable-width font? variable-width will naturally look "off-kilter" if the digits have different widths.

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in a http://jsfiddle.net ? the current provided code does not look anything like your image

Comment: If text (a single word) is larger than its container, then it'll align with the left. To fix this, either increase the width or use different word wrapping.

Comment: I'll get a fiddle going right now as well as try out the couple preliminary things that were suggested.  It's the publicly available "Raleway" font.

Comment: I just tried removing the "width: 50%" property and that appears to have fixed the centering issue.  As Marc B pointed out, the font I am using (Raleway) appears to also have been responsible for part of the "off-kilter" look, so I can simply use a different font to resolve that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not valid to put block elements inside inline elements (spans). This is mostly a matter of center alignment and giving the H4 enough space:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 20px;
}
.voteButton {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.voteTotal {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up voteButton upvoted">></button>
  <h4 class="voteTotal">3</h4>

  <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down voteButton">
    <</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up voteButton upvoted">></button>
  <h4 class="voteTotal">10</h4>

  <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down voteButton">
    <</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  As you pointed out, I had a fundamental misunderstanding about the different display elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add text-align:center to the parent span class.

p.s. I suggest you to remove that width 50% from the voteTotal and change it to something else. If you need further help, please provide a demo link.

Comment: Removing width: 50% appears to have resolved the issue.